# How to import rdf file into named graph?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, tdb

I am new to RDF. I have a FOAFFriends.rdf file in my working directory. I need to import and use a named graph to store it in TDB model rather than unnamed model and then store it in as an external xml file. following code produces blank files. how can i fix this? Also how to know which URI to use?

```
     String directory = "MyDatabases/Dataset1" ;
     Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory) ;

     dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ) ;


     Model model = dataset.getNamedModel("FOAFFriends.rdf") ;

     dataset.commit();


     FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(
     "SamResult.xml");
     model.write(fout);

     dataset.end();
```

Comment: Have you verified that your model is populated? Try using the eclipse debugger or running this line `model.write(System.out)` before the `dataset.commit();` to ensure that your model has been loaded. You could instead try to use the `TDBLoader.loadModel()` method. Also I'm fairly certain that instead of using `dataset.getNamedModel("FOAFFriends.rdf")` you need to use `dataset.getNamedModel("FOAF_URI")` where FOAF_URI is the uri of the file, not the filepath.

Comment: To find the uri of the file, open it in your favorite text editor and look for the `<owl:Ontology rdf:about="example uri" />` tag. Should be near the very top.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got my doubt clarified.

Comment: The code you've posted opens a TDB dataset, and then attempts to retrieve a graph named "FOAFFriends.rdf".  The concept of a named graph in a dataset doesn't have anything to do with the name of files on disk.  TDB uses files on disk for its storage;  that's why you provide a directory when you open the TDB dataset---you're telling TDB where to store its files.  You still need to read your file from disk and store its contents as a named graph in the TDB dataset.  You can use whatever URI you want to name the graph.

Comment: yes I used getNamedModel() for that... and read the rdf file in it by model.read().. thanks..